# How to add an icon to an accordion menu

Tags: javascript, css

I've implemented an accordion that works fine, but I tried to add a `+` to it to open the shutter and a `-` to close it when it is unfolded.

I could not find a way to do so.

Here is my code:

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.question {
  color: #555;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #efefef;
}

.question:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `psuedo` elements i.e. `before` or `after` to add icons as per your need. Inspect accordion example over here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **Span** tag inside your question **div** and give it an absolute position and change its text content depending on your **click event**

Here is an example how to do that:

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
    $(this).find('span').text('+');
  } else {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
    // Add - when its open and + for other Siblings
    $(this).find('span').text('-'); 
    $(this).siblings().find('span').text('+');
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");

body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.question {
  color: #555;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #efefef;
  position: relative;
}

.question:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.symbol {
  position: absolute;
  /* Top Right Bottom Left */
  inset: auto 1rem auto auto;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question<span class="symbol">-</span></div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question<span class="symbol">+</span></div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question.<span class="symbol">+</span></div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may add a toggle class 'active' for the element with class 'question' and add pseudo-element style :before content: "+" not-active and "-" for active class

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question:first-child").addClass('active');
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.question').removeClass('active')
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.question {
  color: #555;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #efefef;
  position: relative;
}

.question:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.question::after{
  content: '+';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.question.active::after{
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```